# Max width grid problem - When changing to 90% goes off the page

Tags: css, image, responsive, css-grid

I'm having trouble with figuring out why when i change the max-width variable from 100% to 90% part of the grid shoots off the page. If you need to see more of the code then please let me know. Would really appreciate anyone's help, thanks.

```css
/* Seasonal Events Grid 
-------------------------------*/

div.jk-seasonal > div {
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
div.jk-seasonal {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
    display: grid;
  grid-column: repeat(6, 1 fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
}
}

/* Seasonal Event1 - Big One
-------------------------------*/

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
/* For desktop: */
.jk-event1 {
 grid-column: span 1 / 2;
 grid-row: 1 / 7;
 background-image: url("http://www.jacquelinekennedy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/jacqueline-kennedy-banner11.jpg");
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 position: relative;
 max-width: 100%;
 min-width: 500px;
 margin:5px;
}
}


/* Seasonal Event2 - Middle Top
-------------------------------*/

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
/* For desktop: */
.jk-event2 {
 grid-column: 2 / 3;
 grid-row: 1 / 4;
 background-image: url("http://www.jacquelinekennedy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/jacqueline-kennedy-banner6.jpg");
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 position: relative;
 max-width: 100%;
 min-width: 300px;
 margin:5px;
}
}


/* Seasonal Event3 - bottom right
-------------------------------*/

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
/* For desktop: */
.jk-event3 {
 grid-column: 3 / 3;
 grid-row: 4 / 7;
 background-image: url("http://www.jacquelinekennedy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/jacqueline-kennedy-banner6.jpg");
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 position: relative;
 max-width: 100%;
 min-width: 300px;
 margin:5px;
}
}


/* Seasonal Event4 - Bottom middle
-------------------------------*/

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
/* For desktop: */
.jk-event4 {
 grid-column: 2 / 3;
 grid-row: 4 / 7;
 background-image: url("http://www.jacquelinekennedy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/jacqueline-kennedy-banner6.jpg");
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 position: relative;
 max-width: 100%;
 min-width: 300px;
 margin:5px;
}
}



div.jk-seasonal > div {
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="jk-seasonal">
  <div class="jk-event1"><a href="http://www.jacquelinekennedy.co.uk/" id="jacqueline-kennedy-vip-wimbledon-tickets"><h3>Strawberries<br>and<br>Perfect Seats</h3></a><p class="jk-seasonal-text">Have the wedding of your dreams professionally planned and managed making sure your special day goes the way you planned.</p><button class="w3-button w3-round">More Information</button>
</div>
  <div class="jk-event2"><a href="http://www.jacquelinekennedy.co.uk/" id="jacqueline-kennedy-event2"><h4>Event 2<br>Name</h4></a><button class="w3-button w3-round">More Information</button></div>
  <div class="jk-event3"><a href="http://www.jacquelinekennedy.co.uk/" id="jacqueline-kennedy-event3"><h4>Event 3<br>Name</h4></a><button class="w3-button w3-round">More Information</button></div>
  <div class="jk-event4"><a href="http://www.jacquelinekennedy.co.uk/" id="jacqueline-kennedy-event4"><h4>Event 4<br>Name</h4></a><button class="w3-button w3-round">More Information</button></div>
</div>
```

[at 100% Max-width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lKyj.png)

[at 90% width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/je2Tr.png)

I also seem to be getting an error in wordpress custom css area when using "fr" ive also added in a screenshot for this:

[When I put the space in to remove the error the grid does not work anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za9Px.png)

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem. Also, it's `1fr` not `1 fr`.

Comment: Thanks will post up the code now, the other problem occurs when i put in 1fr though.

Comment: posted full code now, thanks

Comment: Actually, **less** code in an [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: Have reduced the code to only desktop version which is where i seem to have the problem, thanks